# Regarding $X,Y$ being gamma random variables uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, probability-theory

The proposition is as follows:

> If $X,Y$ are independent gamma random variables with respective parameters $(s,\lambda),(t,\lambda)$, then $X+Y$ is a gamma random variable with parameters $(s+t,\lambda)$.

The answer is supposed to be, letting $Z=X+Y$:
$$f_Z(a)=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda\cdot a}(\lambda a)^{s+t-1}}{\Gamma(s+t)}$$

I would like to understand how to explicitly compute this result, and my work is as follows:

> We know that in general,
>
> $$f_Z(a)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}F_X(a-y)f_Y(y)dy$$
>   where $F_X$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of $X$ and $f_Y$ denotes the probability distribution function of $Y$. Since $X,Y$ are both gamma random variables, we have that
>   $$f_Z(a)=\int_{0}^a \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda(a-y)}(\lambda(a-y))^{s-1}\cdot\lambda e^{-\lambda  y}(\lambda y)^{t-1}}{\Gamma(s)\cdot\Gamma(t)}dy $$
>   $$=\frac{\lambda^{s+t} e^{-\lambda a}}{\Gamma(s)\cdot\Gamma(t)}\int_{0}^a (a-y)^{s-1}y^{t-1}dy$$
>
> Letting K=$\frac{\lambda^{s+t}}{\Gamma(s)\cdot\Gamma(t)}$, we have
>   $$Ke^{-\lambda a}\int_{0}^a (a-y)^{s-1}y^{t-1}dy$$
>   Letting $u=\frac{y}{a}$, we have $du=\frac{1}{a}$, so we end up with
>   $$Ke^{-\lambda a} a^{s+t-1}\int_{0}^1 (1-u)^{s-1}u^{t-1}du$$

The issue I have is proceeding from the final step. How do I end up obtaining
$$f_Z(a)=\frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda\cdot a}(\lambda a)^{s+t-1}}{\Gamma(s+t)}$$
from what I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the properties of the Euler's [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{s-1} u^{t-1}\,du = B(s,t) = \frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(t)}{\Gamma(s+t)}.$$

Comment: Oh my! Thank you, sir. I'd forgotten about the Beta function -_-